# Sistema de redirecionamento com PHP

Tags: php

Olá, como eu poderia fazer um sistema redirecionamento de página com PHP?
Sendo mais especifico, seria o seguinte, tenho uma página de testes com apenas 2 inputs, um para enviar e outro para inserir um texto. Caso ele digite um determinado código corretamente ele é redirecionado para alguma página, do contrario aparece uma mensagem de erro para ele (mas nada como um alert no meio da tela, sou mais para fazer aparecer uma pequena caixa estilizada contendo algum texto, por exemplo "Código inexistente").
 Exemplificando mais, vamos supor tenho esses 4 códigos: `teste1` `teste2` `teste3` `teste4`
 
Eles seriam como senhas, caso o usuário digite o `teste1` ele é redirecionado para a `página1.php` caso digite o `teste2` é redirecionado para a `página2.php` e por ai vai..
 Mas caso ele não digite nada, aparece o tal do erro que eu citei.

Comment: Sua pergunta foi suspensa pela comunidade porque faltam informações para deixá-la mais específica, como de onde vem a lista de códigos (estão num array?), e a parte onde você está tendo problemas (consegue fazer um redirect com URL fixa?). Como está, é muito ampla, inclusive envolvendo aspectos de interface de usuário ("nada como um alert no meio da tela, sou mais para fazer aparecer uma pequena caixa estilizada contendo algum texto"). Sugiro editar a pergunta para deixá-la o mais objetiva possível, e a comunidade pode decidir pela reabertura.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer algo como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
var $campo = $_POST["campo"];
switch($campo) {
    case "teste1":
        header("Location: teste1.php");
    // mais casos
    case "testeN":
        header("Location: testeN.php");
    default: 
        echo "<div class='box-estilizada-erro'>Código inválido</div>";
}
```

Porém se forem códigos que são cadastrados dinamicamente, ou se forem muitos, recomendo fazer uma tabela em banco e verificar lá se existe esse código, daí se existir, faz o redirecionamento, se não, exibe a mensagem.